# How do you Get and Add events to a specific source?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I was successfully able to specify multiple sources:  My SQL server source, and an empty array to hold any user-generated events `userAddedEvents = []`.  The idea was that I could use this array later to "save" new events to my server.

```
var userAddedEvents = []; //container for event objects that will hold user-generated content

var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    eventSources: [
        {
            events: function (fetchInfo, successCallback, failureCallback) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    type: 'post',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", //include fetchInfo in request body instead of form-data
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: JSON.stringify(fetchInfo), //the fetchInfo object must be stringified
                    success: function (data) {
                        events = $.merge([], data.events);
                        successCallback(events);
                    }
                });
            }
        }, //end server source
        {
            id: 'userAddedEvents',
            events: userAddedEvents
        } //end local array source
    ]
});
```

So, here's me trying to add an event to my `userAddedEvents` source...

```
select: function (info) {
    // https://fullcalendar.io/docs/select-callback

    console.log(info)
    console.log('selected ' + info.startStr + ' to ' + info.endStr)

    calendar.addEvent({
      start: info.startStr,
      end: info.endStr,
      rendering: 'background', //v4 and v5 use different terminology
      color: '#ff9f89',
      selected: true, //custom, extended property
    }, userAddedEvents);
    
    calendar.unselect(); //clear the current selection


  },
```

Anyway, long story short... when I try to dump out the results of `userAddedEvents`, it's empty, although, I do *see* new content on my calendar.

**==UPDATED==** with example included... I added a custom button where I attempt to get content from the userAddedEvents array.

*Alternatively* (also shown in the example), I've had success getting ALL events with `calendar.getEvents()`, then using `$.grep` to filter some specific property or extended property.  Ultimately though, I suppose I'm trying to use a "temporary event source" for the sake of convenience -- I can act upon the `userAddedEvents` array, stringify it, empty it, etc.  I do not know how to `getEvents` for a specific source object.

```
    customButtons: {

    getUserCreatedEvents: {
        text: 'Get User Events',
        click: function () {


            console.log(calendar.getEventSources());  //both event sources are listed
            console.log(calendar.getEventSourceById(userAddedEvents)); //missing the id in output {calendar, id, internalEventSource, url}
            console.log(calendar.getEventSourceById('userAddedEvents')); //has the the id in output {calendar, id, internalEventSource, url}
            console.log(userAddedEvents) //the array is empty


            /*
            events = calendar.getEvents();
            // console.log(events)
    
            var filteredResultsGREP = $.grep(events, function (event) {
                return event.rendering === 'background';
            });

            */

            /*
            https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Event-toPlainObject (version 5 only)
            */

            // this WILL show any events added based on the property specified
            // console.log(filteredResultsGREP);



        }
    }

}
```

How do I get the events that are new?  I want to hold all user-created events before I send them to SQL for processing.

Comment: "when I try"... and where and when do you try? Please clarify and show code, in context. Thanks

Comment: okay, I've included the output example :)

Comment: Thanks. Now I look more closely, `userAddedEvents` is just an array. It's not an [event source object](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/event-source-object) or anything else that [addEvent](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/Calendar-addEvent) accepts. So you can't pass it to `calendar.addEvent`, and you can't use it as the ID of an event source for `getEventSourceById` either.

Comment: Try `calendar.addEvent({
      start: info.startStr,
      end: info.endStr,
      rendering: 'background', //v4 and v5 use different terminology
      color: '#ff9f89',
      selected: true, //custom, extended property
    }, "userAddedEvents");` instead - using the string ID of the event source.

Comment: And then `console.log(calendar.getEventSourceById('userAddedEvents'))` should hopefully show an event.

Comment: This is getting closer... I tried specifying an empty array source in `eventSources` like this: `{id: 'userAddedEvents', events: []}` ... examining the EventSourceApi output >> internalEventSource >> _raw ... the id is 'userAddedEvents', but there's an empty array.....  How do I `getEvents()` for an event source with `getEventSourceById()`?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, apologies for totally forgetting about this question, having started to help with it.

After some digging it looks like you can't get the raw events for an individual event source, which is a bit annoying.

So I think actually your simplest approach is just to add the events to your separate array, without worrying about the structure in fullCalendar. Then you can just send that list to the server when you want to save them.

```
select: function (info) {

  var evt = {
      start: info.startStr,
      end: info.endStr,
      rendering: "background", //v4 and v5 use different terminology
      color: "#ff9f89",
      selected: true //custom, extended property
  };
  calendar.addEvent(evt);
  userAddedEvents.push(evt);

  calendar.unselect(); //clear the current selection
},
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/abdVVNM

The only extra complication you might have is if you allow events to be dragged or resized (or otherwise edited) after they've been added, you'll have to sync that with the separate array, which is a bit of extra work.